# What are the differences between these tuning machines?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, tuning

I just got a used Fender Starcaster S1 to compliment my existing Behringer strat.
Upon inspecting it, I noticed that it has different backs on it's tuning machines.
What are the differences between these besides appearance?

[image]

Comment: The quality of the Fender tuning machines is quite a bit better than the behringers.  Other than that, there's probably not much difference.  Beware of very cheap tuners.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside them both you have a cog and a worm gear, which works as per this gif from Wikipedia:

[image]

Worm gears have a very useful property - they can cope with high tension without slipping.

The casing differences are purely cosmetic.

Comment: Fantastic image, sir =)

Comment: Yes, nice image, but how exactly does this address the question?

Answer (score 6):

There are some easily noticeable differences:

1. Tuners on Behringers are attached with screws on the back side, while the ones on Fenders have a nut on the front.
2. There might be differences in the string attachment itself (not pictured here).

Some differences are not as easily spotted, but are a huge deciding factor:

1. For example, **differences in gear ratio.**  Generally, higher-end tuning machines have a **high ratio** for easy, minute adjustments in pitch.
2. In addition, **differences in build quality.**  Lower-end tuners are less likely to hold their pitch, and may be more susceptible to damage from use.